# API Hub using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-api-gateway

I am building an API Hub using AWS API gateway, and was wondering if architecturally this is correct?

The idea is to listen to API endpoints from applications, process these and invoke an internal system API to achieve something.

Is API Gateway + SQS + Lambda the right solution?

Comment: Please add more details around this question, so we can better understand the context

Answer (score 0):

Srinivas, looks like you are wondering whether AWS API gateway can be used as an API platform which contains all features. I am assuming you are thinking of features like Authentication, Multi-tenancy, Analytics, SLA tiers etc. I would request you to explore and compare AWS API gateway to other API platforms like Apigee and Mulesoft Cloudhub API platform.

Pls download the gartner report here - https://www.gartner.com/en/documents/3990768/magic-quadrant-for-full-life-cycle-api-management. In general, Apigee and Mulesoft are the leaders in the API world.